# Applying Kolmogorov's extension theorem

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $S=\left\{0,1,2\right\}, X=S^{\mathbb{Z}}$. Let $S$ be equipped with the discrete topology $\mathcal{D}$, and $X$ be equipped with the associated product topology $\tau$. The set $\mathcal{C}$ of all cylinder sets
$$
C_t[a_0,\ldots,a_m]:=\left\{x=(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\in X: x_t=a_0,x_{t+1}=a_1,\ldots,x_{t+m}=a_m\right\},
$$
where $a_i\in S$ for all $0\leq i\leq m$, is a base of $\tau$. Letting $\mathcal{E}$ denote the product-$\sigma$-algebra on $X$, we have $\tau=\mathcal{B}(X)=\mathcal{E}=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$.

> > **Claim:** Let $p\colon S\to [0,1], p(0)=p(1)=p(2)=1/3$. Then, by setting 
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{P}(C_t[a_0,\ldots,a_m]):=\prod_{i=0}^m p(a_i)
> > $$
> >     for all cylinder sets, we get a probability measure on $\mathcal{E}$.

I tried to prove this claim by using [Kolmogorov's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem#General_form_of_the_theorem).

Proof: Consider $\left\{(\Omega_t,\mathcal{F}_t)\right\}_{t\in\mathbb{Z}}$ with $\Omega_t=S, \mathcal{F}_t=\mathcal{B}(S)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{Z}$. For each subset $J\subset\mathbb{Z}$, define $\Omega_J:=\prod_{t\in J}\Omega_t=S^{\text{card} J}$ and for subsets $I\subset J\subset\mathbb{Z}$, let $\pi_{I\leftarrow J}\colon\Omega_J\to\Omega_I, \omega\mapsto \omega_{|I}$.

Let $F\subset\mathbb{Z}$ be finite. Define a measure $\mu_F$ on $\mathcal{B}(S)^{\otimes\text{card}F}$ by
$$
\mu_F(A)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{\text{card}F}\cdot\text{card}A, A\in\mathcal{B}(S)^{\otimes\text{card}F}.
$$
Then, for all finite subset $F\subset G\subset\mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$
\mu_F=\mu_G\circ\pi_{F\leftarrow G}^{-1}.
$$
By Kolmogorov's extension theorem, there then exists an unique probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that
$$
\mu_F=\mu\circ\pi_{F\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}}^{-1}~\text{ for all }F\subset\mathbb{Z}\text{ finite }.
$$

Then, for some cylinder set, we have
$$
\mu(C_t[a_0,\ldots,a_m])=\mu(\pi_{F\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}}^{-1}(\left\{a_0\right\}\times\left\{a_1\right\}\times\ldots\times\left\{a_m\right\}))=\mu_F(\left\{a_0\right\}\times\left\{a_1\right\}\times\ldots\times\left\{a_m\right\})=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^m=\prod_{i=0}^m p(a_i)
$$
with $F=\left\{t,t+1,\ldots,t+m\right\}$.

So letting $\mathbb{P}$ be $\mu$, I think one has shown that there is a probability measure on $\mathcal{E}$, that has the given property on cylinder sets.

*This is all I can give as a proof. Hopefully, this is not totally stupid. Please give me a feedback.*

Comment: I am not sure how I can show that P does fulfill these properties on $\mathcal{C}$, since I only know which values P takes on the cylinder sets and an union of disjoint cylinder sets does not have to be a cylinder set, so how show f.e. $\sigma$-additivity? - Moreover, I thought that P is the measure that is the result of the extension, which I called $\mu$. I showed that $\mu$ is a prob. measure and then I set P to be identical with $\mu$.

Comment: Moreover, *why* should I show that P is a probability measure on $\mathcal{C}$? The idea was to create $\mu$ as a prob. measure on $\mathcal{E}$ and then to set $P$ (from which we only know its values on cylinder sets) to be $\mu$, since $P=\mu$ on cylinder sets.

Comment: Ehm, wer did the comment from the user go? . .

Comment: Your definition of cylinder  is not the usual one (see Halmos, for instance). The set of cylinders (with the usual definition) is an algebra.  The set $\mathcal{C} $ (the cylinders according to your definition) is just a semi-algebra (assuming $\emptyset, S \in \mathcal{C}$).

Comment: I took the def. from here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set - I guess you mean the notion "cylinder set" related to product-$\sigma$-algebras. I think this is not meant in the link.

Comment: Way 1 is not familiar to me, will look it up.For way 2, I do not know how to verify that P is a prob. measure since only values on the cylinder sets (the ones I defined) are given. So, I chose way 3.

Comment: There are three different ways to prove the result you want: 1. Use the 
Theorem of Countable Product of Measure Spaces (Halmos §38). 2. Prove that  $\mathbb{P}$ is a measure on the semi-algebra $\mathcal{C}$ and apply Carathéodory Extension Theorem. 3. Build $\mathbb{P}$ (as you did) using Kolmogorov Extension Theorem. 
The approach 1 is by far the most direct. The approach 2 is longer, in fact, it repeats for the particular case, part of the proof of the Theorem of Countable Product of Measure Spaces. The approach 3 is the most complex one.

Comment: Are you not familiar with measures defined on semi-algebras and Carathéodory Extension Theorem?

Comment: Sometimes  measures defined on semi-algebras (or in algebras) are called premeasures.

Comment: I know that a premeasure on a semi-ring R can be extended uniquely to $\sigma(R)$. But I do not know how to show that P is a premeasure on the set containg the cylinder sets. I only know the values of cylinder sets, is this enough to show $\sigma$-additivity? I don't see that. That's why I used the Kolmogorov-way instead of the Caratheodory-way.

Comment: The set $\mathcal{C}$  of cylinders (as you defined) is a semi-ring (in fact a semi-algebra).  We prove $P$ is a premeasure on $\mathcal{C}$, just showing that $P$ satisfies the definition of a premeasure on a semi-ring (semi-algebra).  In details: you must prove that $P(\emptyset)=0$ and that: IF a cylinder $A$ is equal to  the countable disjoint union of cylinders $A_i$ then $P(A)=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}P(A_i)$.